# Deserializing XML class conflict

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I'm deserializing from XML and running into a class conflict problem.

e.g.

In my code already, I'll be making reference to `ContentType` class which is actually living in `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentType` or the `Web` class living in `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web`.

e.g

```
var parentCtType = (from c in rootWeb.ContentTypes
                                        where c.Name.ToLower().Trim() == ctParent.ToLower().Trim()
                                        select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

In my XML it reads as such:

```
<ContentTypes>
            <ContentType Name="D Base Document Set" Parent="Document Set" Group="*D">
                <ContentTypeSiteColumns>
                    <Sitecolumn DisplayName="Security" StaticName="SecurityClassification" Group="*DIAColumn" Type="TaxonomyFieldType" TermStore="D" TermSet="Security Classification" DefaultValue="UNCLASSIFIED" Required="TRUE" />
                    <Sitecolumn DisplayName="Enterprise" StaticName="Tax" Group="Enterprise Keywords Group" Type="TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti" TermStore="D" TermSet="N/A" />
                </ContentTypeSiteColumns>
            </ContentType>
            <ContentType Name="D Base Document" Parent="Document" Description="The content type from which all other document content types will inherit." Group="*D">
                <ContentTypeSiteColumns>
                    <Sitecolumn DisplayName="Security Classification" StaticName="SecurityClassification" Group="*D" Type="TaxonomyFieldType" TermStore="D" TermSet="Security" DefaultValue="UNCLASSIFIED" Required="TRUE" />
                    <Sitecolumn DisplayName="Enterprise" StaticName="Tax" Group="Enterprise" Type="TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti" TermStore="D" TermSet="N/A" />
                    <Sitecolumn DisplayName="Notes" StaticName="Notess" Description="For notes giving context to the document.  Additional information can include URL link to another document." Group="*D" Type="Note" Required="FALSE" />
                </ContentTypeSiteColumns>
            </ContentType>
```

In my class I'm deserializing to, I have a class called ContentType and Web (Pretty sure it has be named this since I'm deserializing from that XML with elements that name).

```
public class ContentType
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Name;

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Parent;

        public List<Sitecolumn> ContentTypeSiteColumns;

    }
```

So this class above has to be called ContentType(?) since that's what I'm deserializing to from the XML.

The errors I get are like:

```
Error   4   'testebby.ContentType' does not contain a definition for 'FieldLinks' and no extension method 'FieldLinks' accepting a first argument of type 'testebby.ContentType' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Which disappear if I call the class I'm deserializing to something different, like `ContentTypeZ` but then the deserializing process doesn't work.

How can I work around this? Hope it made sense.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking to Deserialize the XML then this is how i would do it....

Usings.....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

Classes.....

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Sitecolumn")]
public class Sitecolumn
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "DisplayName")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "StaticName")]
    public string StaticName { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Group")]
    public string Group { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "TermStore")]
    public string TermStore { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "TermSet")]
    public string TermSet { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "DefaultValue")]
    public string DefaultValue { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Required")]
    public string Required { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ContentTypeSiteColumns")]
public class ContentTypeSiteColumns
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Sitecolumn")]
    public List<Sitecolumn> Sitecolumn { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ContentType")]
public class ContentType
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ContentTypeSiteColumns")]
    public ContentTypeSiteColumns ContentTypeSiteColumns { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Parent")]
    public string Parent { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Group")]
    public string Group { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ContentTypes")]
public class ContentTypes
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ContentType")]
    public List<ContentType> ContentType { get; set; }
}
```

Code.....

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strXML = File.ReadAllText("xml.xml");
        byte[] bufXML = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strXML);
        MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(bufXML);

        // Deserialize to object
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ContentTypes));
        try
        {
            using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(ms1))
            {
                ContentTypes deserializedXML = (ContentTypes)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            }// put a break point here and mouse-over deserializedXML….
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
}
```

UPDATE 1

this is the XML

```
<ContentTypes>
            <ContentType Name="D Base Document Set" Parent="Document Set" Group="*D">
                <ContentTypeSiteColumns>
                    <Sitecolumn DisplayName="Security" StaticName="SecurityClassification" Group="*DIAColumn" Type="TaxonomyFieldType" TermStore="D" TermSet="Security Classification" DefaultValue="UNCLASSIFIED" Required="TRUE" />
                    <Sitecolumn DisplayName="Enterprise" StaticName="Tax" Group="Enterprise Keywords Group" Type="TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti" TermStore="D" TermSet="N/A" />
                </ContentTypeSiteColumns>
            </ContentType>
            <ContentType Name="D Base Document" Parent="Document" Description="The content type from which all other document content types will inherit." Group="*D">
                <ContentTypeSiteColumns>
                    <Sitecolumn DisplayName="Security Classification" StaticName="SecurityClassification" Group="*D" Type="TaxonomyFieldType" TermStore="D" TermSet="Security" DefaultValue="UNCLASSIFIED" Required="TRUE" />
                    <Sitecolumn DisplayName="Enterprise" StaticName="Tax" Group="Enterprise" Type="TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti" TermStore="D" TermSet="N/A" />
                    <Sitecolumn DisplayName="Notes" StaticName="Notess" Description="For notes giving context to the document.  Additional information can include URL link to another document." Group="*D" Type="Note" Required="FALSE" />
                </ContentTypeSiteColumns>
            </ContentType>
</ContentTypes>
```

I am reading your XML in to a string from a file in the application build folder called xml.xml... you will need to get the XML string from somewhere else or create the xml.xml file and save your XML for the code above to work

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue. There's still another class in here called ContentType

Comment: Your XML (as you posted it) is incomplete, the end tag </ContentTypes> is missing, I don't know if that was intentional or not.... I have updated my answer with the XML that includes the </ContentTypes> tag and everything is working, the entire XML gets de-serialised to deserializedXML

Comment: Yup that was meant to be there, was just incomplete what I sent. I'm still getting the class conflict between this class ContentType and Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.ContentType

Comment: then I need to see more of you code and all the XML, the code in my answer will  de-serialised the XML (plus ending tag that I added) as you posted it....